# We are trying to concatenate two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, concatenation

We are trying to `concatenate` two arrays, tried the `concatenate`, append to list  join array without success. Is there an easy function to turn two lists {a,b,c} and {1,2,3} into {a1,b2,c3}? The arrays are multiples within `CDT's` and we're combining a text array with an integer array.

Comment: Could u plz show some code that you have done so far?

Comment: @Rene I'm sure _What is the use of Enumerable.Zip extension_ wasn't the question and there are other ways to solve this than `Zip()`. No exact duplicate imo

Comment: @fubo though it wasn't the question, the linked dup is a canonical question that solves OP's problem and in fact _answers_ the question. The answers there are almost 100% the same (including sample data) as given here. And I don't want to _delete_ this question, it's a good signpost to find the canonical answer.

Comment: @RenéVogt: however, i doubt if it's the right way to close as a duplicate if it's actually not a duplicate of that. It's like someone asks "how to repair my car gear" and it's closed as a duplicate of "what is the use of a car gear"(where also is shown how to repair it).

Answer (score 2):

Try Linq [`Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) which

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

```
string[] array1 = { "a", "b", "c" };
string[] array2 = { "1", "2", "3" };
string[] result = array1.Zip(array2, (x, y) => x + y).ToArray();
```

in this case it concartenates two strings `(x, y) => x + y`

Answer (score 0):

Here I have assumed that both arrats have the same length:

```
List<string> result;
for(int i=0;i<array1.Length;i++)
   result.Add(${array2[i]}{array1[i]});
```